# Identify the name of the scrolling effect on this site

Tags: javascript, jquery

The site is:

```
       http://www.odanieldesigns.com/
```

What would this effect be called?

Answer (score 0):

That's called a "fade" by most people.

Comment: I was referring to the way the mouse wheel is smoother than a standard webpage. do you know what it is?

Comment: I'm using a Mac, so I don't have a mouse wheel.  Sorry.